# How to do ad-hoc testing of web service PUT methods?

Tags: web-services, http, webinvoke

I've written a web service and it's nice that you can just navigate to http://whatever... and see the response to GETs. Is there some nifty way I can do something similar for PUTs? (presumably involving some tool to write the info that's PUTed).

Obviously I'll have automated tests for these methods, but I'd like to be able to play around with it without code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiddler2.com%2F&rct=j&q=fiddler&ei=FTHDTI6PE8bI4ga27eC5Aw&usg=AFQjCNGyVxcKeoiBFf3LsfsM8apoKVxKLQ&sig2=ZUJe8DhvIj3bPoY4b7js7w&cad=rja). I just saw an example at about 6:00 into [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Getting-started-with-the-WCF-REST-Starter-Kit-Preview-2/).